# jquery won't submit when iphone GO button is pushed

Tags: jquery, iphone, form-submit

*EDIT* - Just realized this is no longer an issue with the new iOS.  I hadn't updated my phone, but this works fine with my iPad, so I assume if I update, it'll work fine.  Thanks.

This question has been asked a few times, but the accepted answer isn't working for me.  I'm hoping someone can spot some dumb error and not come back with "just use input type=submit".

I'm trying to do ajax validation on a login form, so the login form doesn't have a submit button, but rather an input type="button" that calls javascript when clicked.  When using an iphone however, hitting the "GO" button does a literal submit of the form (it posts to the same page and puts the variables in the queryline).

Actually clicking(touching) the button does work correctly.  Only using the GO button messes it up.

Here's my form code:

```
<form name="loginform" id="loginform">
<table>
<tr><td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" id="username" name="username" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" id="password" name="password" /></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td align="right"><button type="button" id="login">Login</button></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

and here is my javascript:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).load(function(){
    $("#login").click( function() {
        checkanswers();
    });
    $("#username, #password").keyup(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode==13){
            checkanswers();
        }
    });
    $("#loginform").submit(function() {
        checkanswers();
    });
});
});
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: No need for the $(window).load as far as I can tell; your code doesn't rely on any asynchronously-loaded resources to be fully present and accounted for.

Comment: I was under the impression that if it had to do with user inputs (like a keyup, or a click) that these were better served in the window.load section.  Is that not accurate?

Comment: No, the element just needs to be in the document model. $(window).load will work but then you wouldn't need the document ready function. Choose one, but I think document ready will work better. Sorry I don't have a response for your GO question, by the way. Not familiar with how iOS' "GO" works.

Comment: Just realized this is no longer an issue with the new iOS.  I hadn't updated my phone, but this works fine with my iPad, so I assume if I update, it'll work fine.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a submit button and in onclick event of the submit button you may do this:

```
onClick="validate();return false;"
```

Then in the validate function return `true` if validation is successful.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an action to the form might work or try to add an `<input type="submit" />` to your form.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("html").off("keypress").on("keypress", function (e) {
    var which = e.which,
    keyCode = e.keyCode;
    if (((which && which === 13) || (keyCode && keyCode === 13))) {
        e.preventDefault();
            //Submit your stuff here.
    }
});
```